# Efficient formula or code to determine number of errors in range VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to retrieve the number (count) of "#N/A" and "#Value" cells within a range (EG A1:A100).

So far I have 2 solutions:

1. Array formula : "=COUNT(IF(ISERROR(A1:A100), 1, 0))" cntr + shft + entr

the solution works but lags a dynamic element. If it does update, it is slow and late to the party.

2. Create a custom formula (nested in a module)

```
Public Function ErrorArray(Rng As Range)
Dim ErrorCount As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Application.Volatile
For Each Cell in Rng
      If Cell.Errors.Items(xlEvaluateToError) = True Then 
          ErrorCount  = ErrorCount + 1
      End If
Next Cell
ErrorArray = ErrorCount
End Function
```

*Please excuse any errors, it did work so thats not the point.

The issue with this solution is the massive drop in workbook performance. Does anyone else know an efficient and dynamic solution, either formula or code?

Comment: What about `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISERROR(A1:A100))`. Still laggy?

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers! I have tried the formula answers which seems to work well (as mine did) for the first 4 sheet references and then not at all afterwards (the next 2). Is there a array formula limit per sheet/references per sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** *The following function will work if called from a vba Macro (`Sub`). The `.SpecialCells` method doesn't seem to work when called from a worksheet via a UDF`

```
Public Function ErrorArray(Rng As Range) As Long
    Dim c As Range
        Set c = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            ErrorArray = c.Count
        Else
            ErrorArray = 0
        End If
End Function
```

If you just want to count only the `#N/A` and `#VALUE!` errors:

```
Public Function ErrorArray(Rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Dim errCount As Long
        Set r = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In r
                'Debug.Print c.Text, c
                Select Case c
                    Case CVErr(2042), CVErr(2015)
                        errCount = errCount + 1
                End Select
            Next c
        Else
            errCount = 0
        End If
 ErrorArray = errCount

End Function
```

If you have very large numbers of errors, the above code can be sped up by using variant arrays. Let me know.

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for this answer, I really like it. I am having an issue filtering the range c. The specialCells function seems to be pulling all cells and values for the specified range even with the type and value parameters. the formula in each cell is something along the lines of """=IF(B2 <> "", IF(G2 > 0, G2, Z2), "") """.  Could this be interfering?

Comment: @hrrbrown Is the formula returning an error? If not, I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. You will need to provide more detail.  If I paste what you wrote into a cell, it does not get selected.

Comment: Hi Ron, the formula doesnt return a error for the majority of the range but i tactically inserted a couple at the end. If there is no error the cell value is blank (""). When I open the range in the locals window, it has pulled the entire input range rather than filtering with the special cells. Thats really it to be honest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @hrrbrown Ok, I have recreated the problem.  The problem is that the `.SpecialCells` method does not work when called by a worksheet function. It only works when called from a Sub.

Comment: Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A100,{"#N/A","#VALUE!"}))
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use for any error:

```
=SUM(--ISERROR(A1:A100))
```

Enter as array formula

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Error Cells Count

- Copy the code into a **standard** module, e.g. `Module1`.
- In `Excel` use it like this: `=ErrorCellsCount(A1:A100)`

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Counts the number of cells containing an error value.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function ErrorCellsCount(CheckRange As Range) As Long
    If Not CheckRange Is Nothing Then
        If CheckRange.Rows.Count > 1 Or CheckRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            ' Check Range contains multiple cells.
            Dim Data As Variant
            Data = CheckRange.Value
            Dim Element As Variant
            For Each Element In Data
                If IsError(Element) Then
                    ErrorCellsCount = ErrorCellsCount + 1
                End If
            Next Element
        Else
            ' Check Range contains one cell only.
            If IsError(CheckRange) Then
                ErrorCellsCount = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```